# How to fix "Failed to process kafka-clients-1.1.1.jar" error in Gradle Build

Tags: java, android, gradle, apache-kafka

I am getting this error when I try to run my Android application after successfully adding Kafka-clients library to my dependencies.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/mac/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/1.1.1/5e96463c4ed422dbed979ae1395176a9c676c090/kafka-clients-1.1.1.jar



Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/mac/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/1.1.1/5e96463c4ed422dbed979ae1395176a9c676c090/kafka-clients-1.1.1.jar
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:442)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
... 51 more
```

Snippet of my build.gradle file looks like this;

```
    dependencies { implementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:1.1.1' }
```

Please how can I possibly be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's gives error because of Kafka support in New Android studio version, try to downgrade dependency version and try rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix it with the latest version of Kaftka Client (2.1.1)